# Open Mapping Theorem Serge Lang Proof

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification, proof-explanation

In his book Serge Lang provides a discussion and then proposing the Open Mapping Theorem as being obvious in the light of the discussion but I am not too sure if I am getting it correctly.

[image: Theorem 6.1]
[image: Discussion Part 1]
[image: Discussion Part 2]
[image: Open Mapping Theorem]

My approach:

Due to the convergence of $f(z)$ there exists A, sufficiently large, such that $a_n\leq A^n$. Then define $F(z)=A^mz^m(1+h(z))$ . We note $f(z) \leq F(z)$ and then we proceed as the discussion ariving at $F(z)=F(z)^m$ and that $F$ is an open mapping. But $f(z) \leq F(z))$, so in the case of $f(z)<F(z)$,  the function $f(z)$ will be bounded (or atleast, since I can't prove its open).

Can somebody please explain to me what Serge Lagn's implied proof is for the general $f(z)=\sum a_nz^n$ with $a_n$ not neccesarly beeing the same as $a^n$?

Comment: Note the open mapping is very easy to prove for (non-constant) analytic functions : let $f$ analytic on $U$ open, for $b \in f(U)$ take $a \in U, f(a) = b$, on a small disk around $a$, $f(z) = f(a)+C (z-a)^n+O((z-a)^{n+1}),C \ne 0, n \ge 1$ thus $f$ is locally surjective onto a neighborhood of $f(a)$ and hence $f(U)$ is open.

Comment: Hey @reuns , thanks for your answer. I've been trying to follow Lang's notation through my hole study of Complex Analysis, thus I fail to understand your second statement (not as fluent in using the big O notation and I am not too sure what C is in this case)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What Serge Lang did is taking $n$-root. Let me clarify his argument. To prove that $f$ is local surjective in a neighborhood of $a$, he used the power series expansion of $f$
$$f(z)=f(a)+C(z-a)^n + \ldots$$
where $C$ is a nonzero constant. Hence
$$f(z)=f(a)+(z-a)^ng(z)$$
with $G(a)\neq 0$. There exists an open disc $U$ centered at $a$ that $g$ is nonzero, so $g$ admits a $n$-root $g_1$, i.e. $g(z)=g_1^n(z)$ on $U$. Note that $g_1(a)\neq 0$. Rewrite $f$ we have
$$f(z)=f(a)+[(z-a)g_1(z)]^n=f(a)+u^n(z)$$
The map $u:z\mapsto (z-a)g_1(z)$ is local analytic isomorphism by Theorem 6.1(c) above, so we can take an open neighborhood $V\subset U$ of $a$ that $u$ maps it isomorphically to an open disc $D$ centered at $0$. The map $w\mapsto w^n$ maps $D$ onto another open disc, hence the image of $f$ contains an open disc of $f(a)$.

In his proof, he didn't want to construct general $n$-root yet, so he did it formally using power series expansion. Indeed, the binomial expansion he used is
$$\begin{aligned}
(1+h(z))^{1/m} &=1+\frac{1}{m}h(z)+\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{m}(\frac{1}{m}-1)h^2(z)+\ldots\\
&=1+h_1(z)
\end{aligned}$$
I don't know how he prove the uniform convergent of the above series, but the uniqueness of power series expansion show that if $h_1$ exists, it must satisfy the equations above.

For the construction of logarithm and $n$-root, if Lang didn't treat them in his book, you should look at other books. The proof of Open Mapping Theorem usually follows straightforwardly from several important results (often Rouché's Theorem). I haven't checked out Lang's book yet, but I think he postponed the treatment of logarithm and $n$-root until he introduced Riemann surfaces, maybe?

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response. You are right that Lang hasn't introduced the n-root.  I am worried that there is a reason for the postponement and me reading about from somewhere else may damage what is intended for me to understand and interpenetrate the concept like. Do you think I should postpone the proof until I get familiar with the concept later on or it is vital to understand it now?

Comment: I took a look at Lang's book, and I found that he had proved the uniform convergence of $h_1(z)$ before, in section Convergent Power Series, page 58. Indeed, he proved that $(1+T)^{\alpha}$ is convergent with radius $1$ when $\alpha \notin \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$. If $h(0)=0$ then $h$ is sufficiently small near $0$, hence $(1+h(z))^{1/m}$ converges.

Comment: Also, when I read books, I often find some parts of the book really hard to follow. At such time I will move on and read other parts of the book, or take a look at other sources. In my opinion, it is no need to stuck with one way of thinking or understanding, and different author provides different insight.

Comment: Thank you very much for the advice. I just want to clarify something. The part when you used the $C(z-a)^n$ is this from the section about the $n-th$ root?

Comment: No, it is just the power series expansion of the analytic function $f$.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Would you mind explaining where $f(z)=f(a)+C(z−a)^n+...$ comes from?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97844/discussion-between-kanye-west-and-withoutfeather).