# Why can we expand an analytic function in such way?

Tags: complex-analysis

In one of the answers to my questions on StackExchange ([Open Mapping Theorem Serge Lang Proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3330381/open-mapping-theorem-serge-lang-proof)) included the fact that a an analytic function can be expanded as $$f(z)=f(a)+C(z-a)^n + \ldots$$ but I am unsure about how the person got to this fact.

My best guess is that by definition since $f$ is analytic on some open set $U$ we have $f(z)=\sum_{i=1}^{m}b_i(z-a)^i=b_o+\sum_{i=2}^{m}b_i(z-a)^i=f(a)  + (z-a)^n\sum_{i=2}^{m}b_i(z-a)^{i-n}$.

My second best guess would be that they used the fact that $f$ being analytic on $U$ implies that $f$ is continuous on $U$ which implies that there exists a function which satisfies $f(z)= f(a) + g(z-a)$ with $g(0)=0$, but again, I am unsure if that's what the person meant.

Could someone shine some light as to how this assertion is made?

Comment: That's just the beginning of the function's Taylor series around $\;z=a\;$ .

Comment: Hi @DonAntonio thanks for the comment. Regarding the expansion, why do you think the first n-1 many terms are missing, as shouldn't they play the biggest role in the behaviour of the function?

Comment: What's your definition of analytic function?

Comment: The Taylor series has that form for some $n$.  It could be $n=1$, but Lang wants to have $C \ne 0$, and take $n$ so that this is the first nonzero term (other than $f(a)$ itself) in the Taylor series.  So of course we must assume $f$ is **nonconstant** to do this.

Comment: @md2perpe I am following Serge Lang's Graduate Conplex Analysis textbook and he defined an analytic function $f$ around a point $z_0$ to be one if there exists a power series such that $f(z)=\sum_{n=o}^{\infty}a_n(z-z_0)^n$

Comment: @GEdgar thanks for the response. It is all clear to me now.

Comment: @MathsWizzard. If $f$ is analytic in $a$ then the expansion you are asking about follows directly from definition of 'analytic'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $\;n\;$ in $\;f(z)=f(a)+C(z-a)^n\;$ can be anything in $\;\Bbb N\;$. For example, if $\;f(z)=e^z\;$ , say, then

$$f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{ z^n}{n!}=f(0)+\overbrace{\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{z^{n-1}}{n!}\right)}^{=C}\,z$$

or if you want any other $\;a\in\Bbb C\;$, then

$$f(z)=e^z=e^ae^{z-a}=e^a\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(z-a)^n}{n!}=\overbrace{e^a}^{=f(a)}+\overbrace{\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(z-a)^{n-1}}{n!}}^{=C}\,(z-a)$$

and etc.