# Why does an a local analytic isomorphism imply a mapping onto a disk?

Tags: complex-analysis

in one of the answers to my questions on StackExchange ([Open Mapping Theorem Serge Lang Proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3330381/open-mapping-theorem-serge-lang-proof)) the person answering the question states that "The map u:z↦(z−a)g1(z) is local analytic isomorphism by Theorem 6.1(c) above, so we can take an open neighborhood V⊂U of a that u maps it isomorphically to an open disc D centered at 0." It is clear to me why it is a local analytic isomorphism, however, it is not clear to me why it being one implies that it maps z to an open disc D and why it is centered at zero. If someone could clarify this for me I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f:D_1\to D_2$ is an analytic isomorphism between the domains $D_1$ and $D_2$, then you can take any open disc $V\subseteq D_2$ and define $U:=f^{-1}(V)$. Then $f\vert_U$ is an analytic isomorphism between $U$ and $V$.
If $f(a)\in V$, then $a\in U$, so $U$ is an open neighborhood of $a$ which is mapped to the open disc $V$ via an analytic isomorphism. Now we just have to center it around $0$ (remember that we can choose the disc to our liking as long as it is contained in $D_2$). If $f(a)=0\in D_2$, we can do this.

Comment: Hi @Vercassivelaunos thanks for the answer. I have a few questions. I will number them because I think it will be easier to address them.

1) I think that in your answer you have a mistake. Shouldn't it be U=f-1(V) ?

2)  Could you explain where "which is mapped to the open disc V via an analytic isomorphism. " comes from?

3) Can we choose the centre to be any point because the set is open meaning that a circle centered at any point with r>0 must exist?

Comment: Hi @MathsWizzard. 1) Yes, you're right. I'll correct it right away. 2) $f\vert_U:U\to V$ is an analytic isomorphism since its bijective by construction and analytic as the restriction of an analytic function to an open domain. So $f\vert_U$ is the analytic isomorphism mapping $U$ to the open disc $V$. 3) Yes, that's exactly it.

Comment: thanks for the quick response @Vercassivelaunos. Just to clarify for the 2nd question, f mapping  onto an open disk is due to the fact that since the inverse exists and it is analytic it implies that the inverse exists is an open set which implies that f is mapped to an open disk. Is this correct?

Comment: $V$ is an open disk. $U$ is then defined as the set which $f$ maps to $V$. $U$ is open because $f$ is continuous, so the pre-image $U$ of the open set $V$ is also open. Now $f\vert_U:U\to V$ is bijective. It's injective because $f$ is injective and the restriction of injective functions is injective. It is surjective because $V$ is contained in the image $D_2$ of $f$, so for every point $w$ in $V$, $D_1$ contains a point $z$ which $f$ maps to $w$. Then $z$ is in $U$, and thus $f$ actually reaches every point in $V$.

Comment: $f$ is also analytic, since its domain $U$ is open and as the restriction of an analytic function to an open domain it is analytic. I hope this covers what you wanted to know, since I'm not entirely sure what you meant.

Comment: what I meant "Is it correct to justify the fact that the image of U is open on the fact that since the inverse exists and is analytic as it must therefore be analytic on some open disk thereby implying that the image of U is mapped on an open disk?"

Comment: You don't need to justify that it's open. The image of $U$ is $V$ by definition, and we chose $V$ to our liking. We chose it to be an open disk, so it's open.